# MOSFET switching causes MCU reset

Tags: mosfet, stm32, reset, brownout

I designed a small USB board with STM32F072 MCU. There is a P-channel MOSFET driven by the STM32 that is supposed to power an external board (with only nRF52832 module and a few ceramic caps).
When the MOSFET is turned on without any load, it works as expected. When I connect the nRF52 board and turn on the MOSFET, the STM32 reboots (probably BOD).
I don't have access to an oscilloscope right now, so I can't observe what is going on exactly.
My suspicion is that I have insufficient regulator input+output caps, missing a gate resistor and that poor PCB routing (via sharing 3.3V power rail that goes to MCU's VCC pin) also doesn't help the situation.
Single 5V->3V3 linear regulator [XC6206P332MR](https://www.torexsemi.com/file/xc6206/XC6206.pdf) is used to power the STM32 and also the external board. Used MOSFET is [IRLML6401](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlml6401pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535668b96d2634&redirId=112291) but I also tried [FDV304P](https://cz.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/FDV304P_D-1808659.pdf) with the same result.

Have you experienced such an issue? What should I try to find the cause of the issue?
[image: schematics]
[image: PCB]

Comment: Perhaps you would like to edit the question to be about the issue or about solving the issue, instead of asking if anyone has experienced such an issue.

Comment: "probably BOD" So actually check the reset source instead of guessing. "My suspicion is that I have insufficient regulator" Measure current consumption. That little 3V3 regulator can only handle 200mA. After which there's a race between the regulator and your fuse regarding who will break first.

Comment: Increase all decoupling capacitors by paralleling more of them. What does your ground plane situation look like?

Comment: @winny Thank you, that's definitely the first thing I improved in the second revision. It's a 4 layer board, inner 2 layers are uninterrupted ground planes with stitching vias.

Comment: Consider only one ground plane and one Vcc.

Answer (score 1):

> Have you experienced such an issue? What should I try to find the
> cause of the issue?

Check the power with an ocilloscope at the MCU VCC power pin and MCU ground. (Also check between MCU VCC and board ground, if you have a diff probe that would be preferable or subtract two measurements with single ended) Set the scope bandwidth to 20 MHz. Check the MCU data sheet to see what the recommendations are for power but if you have anything beyond say 2% of the rail (0.06V for 3.3V) then they're probably is a problem.

If there's a problem you can cut the trace and try and separate the power to the mosfet and MCU. Or you could try and place capacitors near the PIN (which may not work as well)

The best place to cut the trace would be between the mosfet and the cap. Then take a decent gauge wire like a 26 or 28 AWG at least and solder it to both the caps and the 3.3 volt line preferably near the regulator

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions!
I'll measure all the stuff when I regain access to a scope. Meanwhile I'll check the datasheet and try to separate the power paths as you described.